# MariaDB stored procedure generates unclear error, what's wrong?

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb, dbeaver

I still use `MariaDB10`, `Beaver 6.1.3`. I created a SQL query which works fine in `DBeaver`. Now I would like to change it to a stored procedure but still without success.

Following is my code:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE hibiscus.findAllForPivot
 (
     IN jahr varchar(4),         IN kontos VARCHAR(500)
 )
   BEGIN
select 
 VCT.l1_Id,
 VCT.l1_GroupName,
 VCT.l2_Id,
 VCT.l2_GroupName,
 sum( case when (VCT.monat = 1) then dbetrag end ) AS `jan`,
 sum( case when VCT.monat = 2 then dbetrag end ) AS `feb`,
 sum( case when VCT.monat = 3 then dbetrag end ) AS `mrz`,
 sum( case when VCT.monat = 4 then dbetrag end ) AS `apr`,
 sum( case when VCT.monat = 5 then dbetrag end ) AS `mai`,
 sum( case when VCT.monat = 6 then dbetrag end ) AS `jun`,
 sum( case when VCT.monat = 7 then dbetrag end ) AS `jul`,
 sum( case when VCT.monat = 8 then dbetrag end ) AS `aug`,
 sum( case when VCT.monat = 9 then dbetrag end ) AS `sep`,
 sum( case when VCT.monat = 10 then dbetrag end ) AS `okt`,
 sum( case when VCT.monat = 11 then dbetrag end ) AS `nov`,
 sum( case when VCT.monat = 12 then dbetrag end ) AS `dez`
 from hibiscus.V_HibCrosUmsGiroOpaOmaReport VCT
 where  VCT.jahr = jahr and VCT.konto_id in (kontos)
 group by VCT.L1_id, VCT.L1_GroupName, VCT.L2_id, VCT.L2_GroupName;
 END 
 //
 DELIMITER ;
```

I always get the following error:

> SQL-Fehler [1064] [42000]: (conn:26) You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 26
>   Query is : CREATE PROCEDURE hibiscus.findAllForPivot

- If I remove the `group by` line, the same error is at line 25
- If I use the complete `select` statement with `where` and `group by` alone, everything works fine!
- I double-checked the columns in the table.

I will get mad because I can't find the reason.

The columns of the table are (entered by copy&paste):

```
dBetrag
id
Jahr
JahrMonat
konto_id
L1_GroupName
L1_id
L2_GroupName
L2_id
Monat
```

Thank you in advance

rgds OpaHeinz

Comment: Nothing is wrong with this code and I cannot reproduce your issue.Something else is happening which you haven't spotted.

Comment: Do not use parameter names that are identical to column names; you might not get what you expect.  One convention:  precede parameters with an underscore.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to do the same in PhpMyAdmin successful!
Out of this I asume, that the reason is DBeaver or something around.
I will race there a support ticket.

Thank you all for your help!
OpaHeinz